# ApacheDS Studio: JNDI Provider for Ubuntu

Tags: apacheds

When creating a new LDAP connection in Apache Directory Studio, I can use "JNDI (Java Naming and Directory Interface)" as Provider in Windows version, but not in Ubuntu version:

[image: Windows]

[image: Ubuntu]

Why is this the case? How can I add JNDI in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to install the correct Java SDK version (1.8.0) and point the Apache DS configuration to that install, then restart and it should appear. I do not know the location of the config file on Ubuntu but it should be near the binary.

It was not appearing for me as my Apache DS was using openJDK instead (on MacOSX). Once I edited the Info.plist file to point to the desired jdk, it worked.

The configured Java version can be verified by checking About Apache DS >> Installation Details.

Comment: Thanks. For the record: My version was AdoptOpenJDK 11; Oracle 1.8 does work. I had to configure ApacheDS as decribed [here](https://directory.apache.org/studio/faqs.html#how-to-set-the-java-vm-to-use), but the configuration was not applied until I startet the Studio from command line